# Merge or close question on screen time?

Tags: discussion

There are two very good (but very similar) questions right now on ["screen time"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/) and ["iPad"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18732/) usage. The iPad question might well be closed as a dupe.

Both questions garnered similar good responses.

Is there a downside to merging these?

Answer (score 2):

The answers would all fit on both, so yes, I think a close as dupe and merge is the best solution here.