# New tag: [screen-time] for any screen time related issues: TV, computer, tablet, smartphone?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

**Would a new tag: [screen-time] be useful?**

**PROS:**

- The new "screen-time" tag may help in tagging and searching for questions about **any *screen time* related issues that are applicable to more than one device type: TV, computer, tablet, smartphone, etc.**
- **The "screen-time" tag can replace and make more generic many single-device, more narrow tags**, for example, "smartphone", but *only* if in fact the Q&A thread is more generic and applicable to, for example, "smartphone" *and* "tablet".
- A brief search shows that **"screen time" is a common topic on this stack** (337 results as of this writing):
  https://parenting.stackexchange.com/search?q=screen
- The term "screen time" is **becoming more popular with time**. For example, see PubMed search, `Results by year` plot in the upper right corner (2008: 22 articles, 2018: 307 articles):
  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22screen+time%22
- Yet, **many threads either have one, narrow device tag** (e.g., tagged with "computer", but actually applies to other screen types), **or missing the device tag entirely**:

> tag "computer":
> [Up to how many hours of screen time is OK for a teenager for educational purposes?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/up-to-how-many-hours-of-screen-time-is-ok-for-a-teenager-for-educational-purpose)
>
> tag "cellphone":
> [Should we introduce screen time to our 27 month old?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37606/should-we-introduce-screen-time-to-our-27-month-old)
>
> tag "media" (expected: "television"?):
> [How to make my 18-month-old son eat without screen time?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/how-to-make-my-18-month-old-son-eat-without-screen-time)
>
> tag for device/screen missing:
> [10 year old's screen time: Studies and/or Government recommendations?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/31938/10-year-olds-screen-time-studies-and-or-government-recommendations)

**CONS:**

- We have many tags already (but many tags have relatively fewer tags than the "screen" search results above).
- One can search for "screen time", "screen", etc, without the "screen-time" tag (but tags do have many other uses, such as for watching, organizing, etc).

**SEE ALSO:**

[Tags: Brand / product name or umbrella term?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/tags-brand-product-name-or-umbrella-term)

[Merge or close question on screen time?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/merge-or-close-question-on-screen-time)

---

**[EDIT July 29, 2020]:**

New questions that would benefit from this tag keep coming in, for example:

[Limit access to screens (phone, computer) to my kids, whereas I benefitted from "no limit" during my own childhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/40272/33055)

[How do I schedule a timetable for a 4 year old?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/39954/33055)

[How to get my teenage son's enthusiasm back?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/39381/33055)

[Girlfriends Daughter](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/39360/33055)

Comment: You will find that our Meta is very slow; don't be discouraged, it's a good question.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words and the warning! I will be happy to wait as long as necessary for the feedback from the community. And on a related topic, **thank you** for continuing to moderate Parenting.SE, which must be more difficult during the periods of reduced moderation.

Comment: I have added the tag - please feel free to use it. If you do edit it into older posts, please don't do them all at once as that floods the front page. Thank you for persisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems reasonable to me.  If there are more than 300 questions about screen time, having a tag for it makes sense.

I think you did a good job summarizing the pros and cons.  It makes a strong case for it in my opinion.

Comment: Having looked at other tag related Meta questions, it looks like what I wanted to say does qualify as an answer and not just a comment.  Feel free to turn it back to a comment if that is more appropriate.